# AWS RDS gp3 storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm having difficulties understanding how the RDS service of AWS works pricing wise, specifically for the general purpose SSD (gp2). Right now, AWS is saying that I'm using 30 GB a month of general purpose storage.

I ran the following query in pgAdmin after connecting to the database:

`SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('postgres'));`

This query outputs that my database size is currently at 10MB, so why is AWS saying that my general purpose storage usage is 30gb.

The database is using a db.t3.micro instance, and all data is being entered into the database through a Django server running on local. The majority of the data has been entered using Django's object.get_or_create() function.

Comment: You are charged for _allocated_ storage. Think of it as a Hard Disk being allocated specifically for _your_ use. You pay for it regardless of how much you have used inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum storage size for General Purpose SSD (gp2 and gp3) is **20 GiB**.

It's possible that you allocated 30 GiB of storage when you created the database. So now you will be charged for the 30 GiB of allocated space whether you use it or not.

[image: create database console]

DB instances for Amazon RDS use EBS volumes for database and log storage. Depending on the amount of storage requested, Amazon RDS automatically stripes across multiple Amazon EBS volumes to enhance performance. So, regardless of how much storage you actually use, you have been allocated 30 GiB of EBS volume(s).

Keep in mind that with gp2 storage, there is a relationship between volume size and performance, so I don't think a database with only a few MB of storage could provide enough IOPS to run:

> Baseline I/O performance for gp2 storage is 3 IOPS for each GiB, with
> a minimum of 100 IOPS. This relationship means that larger volumes
> have better performance. For example, baseline performance for a
> 100-GiB volume is 300 IOPS. Baseline performance for a 1-TiB volume is
> 3,000 IOPS.

You can read more on Amazon RDS storage [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Storage.html).